# How to run a batch (.bat) file in .NET that in one machine runs and in another wont

Tags: c#, .net, iis, batch-file

When I start a process that starts a `BAT` file with arguments locally all is working fine.  I  uploaded this site to a windows server and then a process failed running this process.  It is just executing the code and nothing happened.

I tried `UseShellExecute = false` and running it with `cmd` and without...

What else can I check?

Comment: show code if you want to get help

Comment: are you trying to run a process remotely? or on the same machine? (like @SteveB wrote, show code)

Comment: trying to run it on the same machine, locally

Answer (score 0):

Start with dependencies. For example:

1. Do you have cygwin or something similar on the server that will actually run a bash shell?
2. Does the user executing the process actually have rights to start the bash shell?
3. Does the user executing the process have rights to perform the actions within the bash script?
4. Are their file path or environment variable dependencies? Do those paths and variables exist?

One way to test would be to log onto that server under the user account used to execute the script to see if you can run it yourself.

It's entirely likely the bash script is failing and hanging trying to prompt the user for input.  It's also possible UAC is on and the script needs elevated permissions to perform the actions.  Without seeing the script it's hard to tell.

Comment: 1- My IIS server runs other `bat` scripts, so i thinking its not the problem   2- The user have rights,its starts the script but never ends. 3- I think YES because running its on `cmd` works. 4- All the paths and variables defined well.  When I running its simply on cmd its ok.

Comment: @Igor: I'm confused.  Are you talking about bash or bat? Those are completely separate things.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i am talking about BAT file

Comment: @Igor:  Without knowing what it is that batch file is doing its going to be impossible to give you more direction.  I truly believe it is a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly having a security/permission issue. Check your server's event log (especially the security event log). Also, if you can, running SysInternals Process Monitor (procmon) on the server will also probably help if nothing else will.

Unless you have set up your web site to use impersonation, it will be running using a local, limited account. For Windows Server 2008, the DefaultAppPool will use the local `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` identity, which almost certainly doesn't have permissions to invoke bash.

It probably works on your local development machine because Visual Studio will be impersonating you (probably a local administrator) in order to debug your application.

To solve this, you'll need to either grant permissions to the identity being used for the application pool for your site to execute bash, or (and this is probably easier) change the identity of the application pool to a domain user (or a local user, at least).

Comment: Well i changed the pool to `Default Pool` and tried all the pool's, and still its doesn't working. its actually invoked because i see the results (directories created) but all the next steps are canceled. I am talking about the `ant` process that should use java to create apk file. In `cmd` its working well.

Comment: First, your environment variables (like `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` can be different for your identity (when you use `cmd`) than for the identity for the DefaultAppPool. Make sure you have set those as System environment variables. Second, you should try some diagnostics within the `.bat` file. Make sure that arguments (i.e. `%1`) are what you think they should be. Use `@echo %1` to output the value, and use `mybatch.bat > logfile.txt` to capture the output (where `mybatch.bat` is the name of your `.bat`. file).